# Laravel - Seeder para rellenar tabla

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-6, laravel-7

tengo un seeder que añade dos registros en una tabla y lo tengo de esta forma, tal como esta funciona pero claro...si tengo 20 tipos tendré que crear "20 try catch" ya que he probado a poner un try y dentro todas las causísticas pero en el primer "error" sale del try.

La pregunta es como hacer esto más óptimo.

```
<?php

 use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

 class CarTypesSeeder extends Seeder
 {
/**
 * Run the database seeds.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function run()
{

    try {
        DB::table('car_types')->insert([
            'id' => 'LARRY',
            'description' => 'Camión',
        ]);
    }
    catch (Exception $exception) {
        var_dump('Skip types :)');
    }

    try {
        DB::table('car_types')->insert([
            'id' => 'car',
            'description' => 'Coche',
        ]);
    }
    catch (Exception $exception) {
        var_dump('Skip types :)');
    }

  }
}
```

Gracias por adelantado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes encapsular el intento en un método privado

```
<?php
    
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Exception;

class CarTypesSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $records=[
         ['id' => 'LARRY', 'description' => 'Camión'],
         ['id' => 'car', 'description' => 'Coche'],
         ['id' => 'mike', 'description' => 'Motocicleta']
        ];
        foreach ($records as $record) {
            $this->attemptInsertion($record);
        }
    }
    /**
     * Intenta insertar un registro
     *
     * @param array{id:string,description:string} $record
     * @return void
     **/
    private function attemptInsertion(array $record):void
    {
        try {
            DB::table('car_types')->insert($record);
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            dump(sprintf('Skip type %s', $record['id']));
        }
    }
}
```

pero no creo que el var_dump sea apropiado. A lo mejor sería más reutilizable manejar un registro de inserciones y  fallas

```
<?php
    
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Exception;

class CarTypesSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Registros insertados, una lista strings que son el id del registro
     *
     * @var array<string>
     */
    private $insertados=[];
    /**
     * Registros fallidos, una lista de arrays de la forma ['id' => xxx, 'message' => yyy]
     *
     * @var array<array{id:string,message:string}>
     */
    private $fallidos=[];
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $records=[
         ['id' => 'LARRY', 'description' => 'Camión'],
         ['id' => 'car', 'description' => 'Coche'],
         ['id' => 'mike', 'description' => 'Motocicleta']
        ];
        foreach ($records as $record) {
            $this->attemptInsertion($record);
        }
        dump([
            'insertados'=>$this->insertados,
            'fallidos'=>$this->fallidos
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Intenta insertar un registro
     *
     * @param array{id:string,description:string} $record
     * @return void
     **/
    private function attemptInsertion(array $record):void
    {
        try {
            DB::table('car_types')->insert($record);
            $this->insertados[]=$record['id'];
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            $this->fallidos[]=[
                'id'=>$record['id'],
                'message'=>$exception->getMessage()
            ];
            
        }
    }
}
```

Para tu caso concreto ¿Qué tipo de error esperas en el try/catch? Si se trata de manejar el caso de registros repetidos (e.g. quieres asegurarte de tener todos los tipos de vehículo pero no puedes limpiar la tabla cuando inventas un vehículo nuevo por un tope de FK) puedes usar [updateOrInsert](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#updates) en vez de `insert`.

```
 DB::table('car_types')->updateOrInsert(
            ['id'=>$record['id']],
            ['description'=>$record['description']]
 );
```

Con este approach podrías añadir atributos a tus tipos de vehículo y volver a ejecutar el seeder sin romper nada. Por ejemplo pensemos que agregas marca y color. Corres la migración y luego llenas los campos nuevos con lo que gustes:

```
 DB::table('car_types')->updateOrInsert(
     ['id' => 'car'],
     ['description' => 'Coche', 'color'=>'rojo', 'marca'=>'Ford']
 );
```

Ojo, el `updateOrInsert` es un método del Query Builder. Si trabajas usando un modelo (e.g `CarType`) en vez del nombre de la tabla textual, vendría siendo

```
 \App\CarType::updateOrCreate(
            ['id'=>$record['id']],
            ['description'=>$record['description']]
 )
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, así lo he implementado.

Answer (score 2):

Personalmente no me preocuparía tanto en lo referente a la creación de bloques *try/catch* en un seeder ya que estos se utilizan para el manejo de errores y excepciones en la lógica de tu código, y un seeder (se supone) que es algo que vas a hacer una o unas pocas veces para llenar tu tabla de datos de prueba y poder trabajar más rápidamente.

En el caso de que haya algún error en la inserción de los datos, Laravel se ocupará de soltarte el error igualmente. Aún así, creo que lo que estás haciendo es perfectamente posible y no debería darte error, por lo que tendrías que investigar qué tipo de error te da.

Creo que la forma óptima de hacer esto sería que te creases una clase propia del tipo "CustomFaker" para llenar la base de datos con tus propios datos de prueba (si es que quieres que sean unos datos concretos. En caso contrario con utilizar un Faker de los que ya hay por la red creo que te valdría). Dado que esto se escapa de la pregunta principal, me centraré en abordar directamente tu problema:

Declara un array con tus datos de prueba:

```
$car_types = array(
    ['id' => 'LARRY', 'description' => 'Camión'],
    ['id' => 'car', 'description' => 'Coche'],
);
```

A continuación haz un bucle for/foreach para ir haciendo el llenado de uno en uno, pasándole como parámetro cada uno de los elementos del array:

```
$n = count($car_types);
for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++){
    DB::table('car_types')->insert($car_types[$i]);
}
```

No se si estarás utilizando *factories* para tus llenados, pero también sería conveniente que los mires. Suelen ser muy útiles.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el comentario, 1000 gracias